# How to calculate which item of panel was selected

Tags: c#, panel, counting

I'm programing a little C# program for browsing pictures, but I got stuck.

I have a `Panel` full of `PictureBoxes`, is there any way to calculate number of the `PictureBoxes` that were clicked on? For example, if I have a `ListBox` I can easily type `listBox1.SelectedIndex` and get the number.

I assume that it's not that easy with `Panel`, but is there actually any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you actually want to do. There is no built-in property of `PictureBoxes` that make or mark them selected.

You can get the index  of the `PictureBox` in the `Panel`'s `Controls` collection in its `Click` event like this:

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int index = yourPanel.Controls.IndexOf(sender as PictureBox );
}
```

You can and probably should assign the **same** event to **all** PBs' `Clicks`!

If you simply want to work with the `PictureBox` write

```
PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
pb.Image = ...
```

Or you could loop over the `Controls` to find one with `Focus`. But even if it was there that would only be the keyboard focus, and, as there can only be **one**, this would not persist even a single `Button` click.. So this is **not recommended**.

So if you want to refer to the last clicked PB simply store it in a class variable or maybe in the `Panel's Tag`:

```
PictureBox selectedPB  = null;

private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   selectedPB  = sender as PictureBox;
   // or 
   yourPanel.Tag = sender as PictureBox;
}
```

If you want to collect several PBs you can do so by adding them to a `List`:

```
List<PictureBox> clickedBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb  = sender as PictureBox;
   if (!clickedBoxes.Contains(pb) ) clickedBoxes.Add(pb);
}
```

and access the number as the `clickedBoxes.Count` ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'SelectedItem' property of your ListBox and bind it to a property on the ViewModel.

If you are using just something like `StackPanel`? Then no, StackPanel does not have this functionality built in. Use a ListBox with a custom Template.